# I just installed Mythbuntu, what is the MySQL root password?

Tags: mysql, mythbuntu, mythtv

After installing Mythbuntu, I am unable to access MySQL as I don't remember setting a root password. What is the default password?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Early versions allowed blank root password. Newer versions set root password to the main user login password during the install.

Comment: The default password is empty in older versions - You can try to log in using "mysql -u root".

In newer versions as said, root password is the same as the login password.

Answer (score 1):

Please reset MySQL password as below:

1. Ctrl + Alt + T to launch terminal
2. sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
3. New password for the MySQL "root" user: mysqlsamplepassword
4. Repeat password for the MySQL "root" user: mysqlsamplepassword

Wish it helps!

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL Administrator gives great Management GUI with debian-sys-maint account whose username and password are present in /etc/mysql/debian.cnf you can configure all accounts as super user

see if it helps

Comment: debian-sys-maint can also be used for mysqlcheck REPAIR instructions.